# echo if statement if key is present in array

Tags: php

I want to create an if statement true if a key in an array is present but got nothing. Could someone of you help me. Sorry I'm not too good with php.
Thank you.
Here is the code.

```
$array = array('0' => ' Default Size ',
               '1' => ' 2X Plus Size ',
               '2' => ' 3X Plus Size ');

foreach($array as $id=>$text) {
  $sizes[] = array('id' => $id, 'text' => $text); }

if(array_key_exists("0", $sizes)) {
    echo 'No Oversize Size';
}
```

Comment: you got a multidimensional array, direct call of `array_key_exists` function will not help you in this case

Comment: On PHP>=5.5: `array_key_exists( array_column( $array, 'id' ), "0" )`

Comment: `'` missing `'2' => ' 3X Plus Size );`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ;)

```
$array = array(
  '0'=>' Default Size ',
  '1'=>' 2X Plus Size ',
  '2'=>' 3X Plus Size ');

$sizes = array();
foreach($array as $id=> $text){
  $sizes[] = array(
    'id'=>$id,
    'text'=>$text);
}

if(array_key_exists("0", $sizes)){
  echo 'No Oversize Size';
}
```

Comment: That was great. Thank you.